# Compute similiarty between labels

Tags: k-means, unsupervised-learning, accuracy

I have a labeled dataset and I created a duplicate of this dataset and removed the labels and applied K-means clustering with k= the number of labels in the original data set I want to compute similarities between labels to test the efficiency of the algorithm any ideas?

Comment: One thing you can do is , you have data A - which contains labels and data associated with it, you have another data B, with labels(clusters) and data associted with it. You can look at how your features are distributed and understand the similarities.

Comment: I have 26 feature and that is a lot to compare should i do some dimensionality reduction to ease the processor do I have to do it with 26 features

Comment: I think you can do chi-square test or calculate cohen kappa score to validate your model efficiency.

Comment: i want to calculate based on the features of each class ie:comapre each created class with each original class based on features not labels themselves and see the similiarties